# CSRF Token Verification Failed

Tags: python, html, django

I see this question has been asked many times - but I cannot determine what specifically I am doing wrong. Could anyone help me identify what is wrong? I have the CSRF token there but I feel I must be doing something wrong in the view?

views.py

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)

            return render('test.html')


    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

register.html

```
  <form method="POST" class="border border-light p-5">

  {% csrf_token %}

    <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Registration</p>

    {{form.username}}

    {{form.email}}

    {{form.password}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block my-4" type="submit">Register</button>


  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use CSRF tag in your view? 
You should import:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

then add csrf_excemp before your function definition like this:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def update(request):
```

I hope it solve your problem